# Using SQLite as production database, bad idea but

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, production-environment

We are currently using postgresql for our production database in rails, great database, but I am building the new version of our application around SQLite. Indeed, we don't use advanced functions of postgres like full text search or PL/SQL. Considering SQLite, I love the idea to move the database playing with just one file, its simple integration in a server and in Rails, and the performance seems really good -> [Benchmark](http://www.sqlite.org/speed.html)

Our application's traffic is relatively high, we got something like 1 200 000 views/day. So, we make a lot of read from the database, but we make a few writes.

What do you think of that ? Feedback from anyone using or trying (like us) to use SQLite like a production database ?

Comment: SQLite supports full-text search…

Comment: Yeah, but it's not as powerfull as postgres'one. Anyway, we don't use full text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do lots of reads and few writes then combine SQLite it with some sort of in-memory cache mechanism ([memcache](http://memcached.org/) or [redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/) are really good for this). This would help to minimize the number of accesses (reads) to the database. This approach helps on any many-reads-few-writes environment and it helps to not hit SQLite deficiencies - in your specific case.

Comment: Have you already put this architecture to production? If so, what kind of an experience is/was that?

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is designed for embedded systems. It will work fine with a single user, but doesn't handle concurrent requests very well. 1.2M views per days probably means you'll get plenty of the latter.

Comment: The SQLite docs has a full page of docs that discusses the problem and how they tried to fix it in version 3: http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html

Comment: I agree, but it's only about write not read. If you use something like asynchronous write or in-memory cache mechanism, you loose data integrity but it's so much faster.

Answer (score 1):

For doing only reads I think in theory it can be faster than an out-of-process database server because you do not have to serialize data to memory or network streams, its all accessed in-process. In practice its possible an RDBMS could be faster; for example MySQL has pretty good query caching features and for certain queries that could be an improvement because all your rails process would use this same cache. With sqllite they would not share a cache.