# How to deploy Rails app to EC2 (Amazon)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

Guys, help me please to deploy my Rails app to AWS EC2.
If you can, write full information about prefer my app files to deploy and other.
Im using: SQlite
Dont using: git

Comment: You need to read.

[this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts.html) and [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/deploy-your-rails-app-to-aws/). 

Good luck with your deployments

Comment: Using Capistrano is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the options already mentioned in the comments, I'd consider using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk which will help provision all the necessary AWS resources (including a database, load balancer, security groups). See: https://medium.com/@jatescher/how-to-set-up-a-rails-4-2-app-on-aws-with-elastic-beanstalk-and-postgresql-3f9f29c046e2#.shg7u87kv

It's also worth considering whether you really want to use SQLite in production rather than something more powerful like Postgres or MySQL. This thread has a good discussion of some the relevant issues:
[Using SQLite as production database, bad idea but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097396/using-sqlite-as-production-database-bad-idea-but)